# A-Z loop in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

For a project, I have to loop through the alphabet and run a search for each letter against some values in a database. The function would return the number of matches for each letter.

I would like to be able to do this in a SQL Stored Procedure, but I'm not certain how I could do a 'FOR letter = A to Z' loop in a SP. Does anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: The easy way, create a table "alphabet" and populate it with A to Z ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That wouldn't work in this case though unfortunately.

Comment: @Mark, why wouldn't it? Seems like a reasonable solution that might perform even  better than a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop going from 65 (A) to 90 (Z), and use the [T-SQL CHAR() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx).

Of course, I'm assuming that you are using a SQL Server database. If not, please post the DB you're using.

Comment: Perfect, that did it - I had no idea that function was in SQL! Many thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

it depends according to alphabet if you only need English characters you can do a loop from 65 (ascii for A) and 90 (Z) and use `char letter = (char)i` to get the letter.

If you also need non-English ones just set a web config setting "ABC......Z" and loop through it.

Answer (score 2):

```
with ATable(c) as
(
  select cast('A' as CHAR(1)) as c
  union all
  select CHAR(ASCII(c)+1) as C from ATable where C<'Z'

)
select * from ATable
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11628)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "group by" and possibly include "count" in the query too. you can find further information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH Alphabet AS 
(
    SELECT CHAR(65) AS Letter, 65 AS Code
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CHAR(Code + 1),  Code + 1
    FROM Alphabet
    WHERE Code < 90
) 

SELECT Letter 
FROM Alphabet
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH alpha AS
(
    SELECT 65 AS c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c + 1 FROM alpha
    WHERE c < 90
)
SELECT CHAR(c) FROM alpha
```